# Resetting my transforms but I can't do an even bevel

Tags: bevel

I'm having some basic problems with bevels. Or rather with resetting the scale of my object.

To recreate my problem.

1. Create  abox
2. scale it in x:10, and z 0.1
3. ctrl+A choose apply scale to deltas
4. select long edge on the mesh and ctrl+b to bevel. Bevel is not even.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7349#7349

Comment: Why applying scale to *deltas* on the step 3? Applying scale values (Ctrl+A > Scale) freezes transforms just fine so with that there's absolutely no difference if you scale in Object mode or Edit mode, just make sure to actually use that Ctrl+A > Scale

Comment: I was adviced to use reset scale delta, which makes it look like it worked.  Your solution works though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select your object in object mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then Apply "Scale"

or

Scale your object in "Edit mode" rather than Object mode, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> "Bevel Edges" in will be even.

Comment: Thanks but if I do "apply scale" the object starts scaling. I'm happy with the look of my mesh, just want to freeze all transforms. It works when I export and import mesh as an .obj so surely there must be a way in Blender?

Comment: What about Scaling the mesh in Edit Mode, you could select the mesh "Ctrl+A" and "S"  to scale, then you won't have to use Apply Transformations menu.

Comment: If there is no way to reset transforms I will do all my scaling in edit mode from now on. I just need to be careful not to scale in object mode.